# Using a function to append numerous lists at once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm try to use a list as an argument in a function that appends user input into a list

```
itemno, itemdescrip, itempr = [], [], []

def inpt(x):

    n=0
    while n < 10:
        n+=1
        x.append(int(input("What is the item number?")))


inpt(*itemno)
print(itemno)
```

I expected the output to be 1 when I input 1 into the function but got the error: TypeError: inpt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:itemno, itemdescrip, itempr = [], [], []
:
:def inpt(x):
:
:    n=0
:    while n < 10:
:        n+=1
:        x.append(int(input("What is the item number?")))
:
:
:inpt(itemno)
:print(itemno)
:--
What is the item number? 1
What is the item number? 2
What is the item number? 3
What is the item number? 4
What is the item number? 5
What is the item number? 6
What is the item number? 7
What is the item number? 8
What is the item number? 9
What is the item number? 10
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

you just need to remove the "*" from your function call

Comment: feel free to give this answer a vote up/answer tick as it helps me out a lot ;)

Comment: sorry i forgot :))

Answer (score 1):

When you prefix a sequence with `*` in a function call, you're telling it to [*unpack*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the sequence; that is, present each member of the sequence as an individual argument to the function. In your code:

```
inpt(*itemno)
```

Since `itemno` is empty, you're telling it to unpack nothing into the function arguments. As a result, that function call is equivalent to:

```
inpt()
```

Since your `inpt()` function requires an argument, it throws that error. I'm not sure why you thought the `*` was required, but the simple fix is to remove it, which passes the list itself to the function:

```
inpt(itemno)
```